# What is the Reverse key for Alt + Shift + G in STS

Tags: eclipse

I was looking how to find `Spring` bean references within STS and I found the shortcut key `Alt + Shift + G` that brought up a ribbon in my editor which is annoying. Does anyone know how to remove it. Is there any reverse key for it.

Comment: Show a screen shot of this "ribbon" so we know what it is.

Comment: I've added the image above.

Comment: By the way, you might want to black-out the parts of your screen shot that show a company name or other proprietary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the Java Editor Breadcrumb. It's a toggle-able feature, by default I don't think Eclipse assigns a keyboard shortcut to it, but maybe STS adds one.

In any case, since it's toggle-able, repeating the same keyboard shortcut that enabled it should also disable it. There is also a toolbar button for it, shown here:

[image]

If you don't have that toolbar button visible, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to bring up **Quick Access**, then type `breadcrumb` in the Quick Access box to find the command that toggles it on/off.

[image]

Comment: Perfect it worked. I don't have the button but Ctrl + 3 did the trick.